# Queue of Arrays in C#

Tags: c#

Need to create two Queues of Arrays with 4 ints in every queue.

Something like:

```
Queue1[1] {int i1, int i2, int i3, int4}
Queue1[2] {int i1, int i2, int i3, int4} etc..
```

Same for Queue2

~~Edit~~

I wanted to keep track of ints that were randomly generated.
Ended up using a linked list with objects.
So i created an object with all the ints i wanted and then called a linked list.

```
LinkedList<RandomInts> Q = new LinkedList<RandomInts>();
```

using:

```
Q.ElementAt(indexOfObject).Whatever();
```

did the trick just fine. Thanks!

Comment: are you familiar with the term `new` in regards to creating and pre-defining the size of arrays..? this is what Google is there for.. please do a google search on `Queues...etc`

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: why are you using a queue, if you know there is going to be 4 ints every time why not just use an array of arrays

Comment: First item of queue must be removed after reaching its destination thats why. Array holds destination, gender and other 2 ints. I cant find how to make it happen in C#, thats what i asked. How do i make the queues and access them after in order to fill them or use them in ifs/switches.

Comment: Why do you think you need a queue of arrays for this? Why not just have a queue of ints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy. A queue of ints is no different than a queue of any other type, really. You could just as easily have a queue of lists or a queue of queues or anything like that.

I'm using the queue constructor that accepts an IEnumerable to initialize these by the way. In the first case, I'm building a queue from an array of arrays of ints.

In the second case, I'm building a queue from an array of ints. I show that as an example because it's unclear from your post that you actually *need* a queue of arrays. If every queue just contains four ints, why not just create queues with 4 ints in them? Why bother with the whole queue of arrays thing?

Either way, here's teh codez:

```
        // Here you have it - a queue of arrays
        // Really, it's no different than a queue of any other type
        Queue<int[]> queue = new Queue<int[]>(
            // Construct the queue from the following array of arrays
            new[]
            {
                new[] { 3, 2, 1, 0 },
                new[] { 32, 24, 234, 3 }
                // Whatever you want
            }
        );

        // If all you want is a queue with four ints, why bother with the queue of array thing?
        // You can initialize a queue with some numbers like this
        Queue<int> queueOfInts = new Queue<int>(new[] { 3, 2, 1, 0 });
```

Comment: I ended up using Linked Lists that are consisted of objects. 
    LinkedList<RandomPerson> q = new LinkedList<RandomPerson>();
using q.ElementAt(indexOfObj).Whatever(); did the trick. Thank you!!